# How do I convert $y= 2x^{2} + 16x$ into the vertex form (i.e. $y=a(x-h)^{2}+k$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried looking up the "process" of solving that equation, but I couldn't really find the exact way to solve it.

Isolating the $2$ from $2x^2$ might be one of the way, but I couldn't exactly find out what I would have to do after that.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complete+the+square+2x%5E2%2B16x

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange. A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here. For typesetting your equations, please use MathJax:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Have you heard of “completing the square?”

Answer (score 4):

It is $$2x^2+16x=2(x^2+8x)=2(x^2+8x+16-16)=2(x+4)^2-32$$

Answer (score 1):

While Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer is valid, I'd like to present a more intuitive approach.

Recall: the vertex form of a parabola is given by $y = a(x - h)^2 + k$, for vertex $(h,k)$. For the sake of argument, we can expand that form by foiling the squared term:

$$y = ax^2 - 2hax + ah^2 + k$$

We seek to write $y = 2x^2 + 16x$ in this form. Notice, however, that to generate the same parabola, we will need constants $a,h,k$ such that the two equations are equal. That means we set them equal to each other:

$$2x^2 + 16x = ax^2 - 2hax + ah^2 + k$$

In the interest of clarifying my next step, I will add some extra terms and parentheses:

$$(2)x^2 + (16)x + (0) = (a)x^2 + (-2ha)x + (ah^2 + k)$$

What would it mean for these two polynomials to be equal? Well, the constant terms would equal, the coefficients of the linear term $x$ would be equal, and the coefficients of the quadratic term $x^2$ would be equal. That is to say, we would have three equations:

$$\begin{align}
2 &= a \\
16 &= -2ha \\
0 &= ah^2 + k \\
\end{align}$$

The first equation outright gives us $a = 2$.

Plug that into the second equation and thus $16 = -4h$. Solve for $h$ and you get $h = -4$.

Plug *both* into the third equation and you get $0 = 32 + k$. Thus, $k = -32$.

Now we just substitute the $a,h,k$ we found into the vertex form:

$$y = a(x - h)^2 + k = 2(x - (-4)^2 + (-32) = 2(x+4)^2 - 32$$